# Does Daniel 9:27; teach two weeks, and at the half period of the second week is when he causes to cease? According to the Lo Ammi principle?

Tags: grammar, daniel

"And he will strenghthen the people of the covenant for week one and a half the week (at the half of the following), he shall cause to cease..."

So here, the view is not that the sacrifices, ceases in the middle of the first week, "and a half the week" seems like strange grammar
but could the art.be signifying that it is the half of the next week that follows "week one"; so he shall cause to cease at the 10.5 period out of 14; which strengthen/training, before the ceasing, goes along with how the saints will be handed over to the beast at the time of tribulation (Dan.12), so the remaining half a week, corresponds to the 1260 prophetic days in the book Revelation to find its prophetic fufillment.

There are a possible 3 mystical weeks not counted toward the first set of weeks 7X7; do to the remaining years of the Babylon judgment see Lo-ammi companion bible, by E.W Bullinger.

Example: When we come to Acts 13:16-22 the Apostle Paul gives a computation regarding Israels History. When we add this up (40 yrs.= in the wilderness; 450 yrs.= Judges period;40 yrs.= Saul’s rein;40yrs=David’s rein, cp.1 Ki.2:11= total 570 yrs.).

When we turn to 1 Kings6:1 there is a difference in the number of years given concerning Paul’s computation.

It says in the 480th year after the children of Israel came out of Egypt that in the fourth year of Solomon’s rein that in the second month that he began to build the temple (1 Kings 6:1). Solomon=3 yrs. bring us to the 480th yr. after the people left Egypt.

The answer is 93 yrs. and the reason for this is the nation was judged by God during the Judges period, when we add up those periods it comes to the exact number of 93 (Jud.3:8=8yrs; 3:14=18yrs; 4:3=20yrs; 6:1=7yrs; 13:1=40yrs =93yrs.) showing us that when Israel is in judgment, the prophetic clock stops.

But my question just concerns the Hebrew, but if anyone is wondering that the computation would not make sense, not so as refenced to the companion bible above.

The fufilled application of these veses would of came around Peters vision Acts.10:7-19;linking his vision with the detestable creepy things;the same "creepy thing" animal imagery is used of Israels national indictment of spiritual harlotry, for their national judgment of Lo-Ammi,where "abomination" and "ceasing" to be a Nation;are linked together(Jer. 7:30 34;32:34;Hosea.2:11;3:4;Ez.8:10;Dan.926-27); corresponding to the Acts period, where Israel was beginning to be judged as "not my people" filling up their sins all the way (1Thes.2:16;Acts.28:25-28;cp.Rom.9:25).

Comment: The 70 weeks in vv24-27 are made up of 7+62+1. If you add a second week at the end, your total is 71

Comment: There is what is called the Lo-ammi principle see companion bible. also, the term half, is a break in language in "week" computation, which is an indication of a change in what just mentioned. also, the difference between times, weeks, and days, i believe are different ways to determine when Israels time clock is being counted or the worlds time as far as them being in judgment, still needs a lot of work, but just know that there is some mystery in the computation so dont count stuff out. can you answer my question about the hebrew?